# Safari 8.0 (Yosemite) returns nothing on mousemove

Tags: javascript, safari, mousemove

I don't know if it has always been like that in Safari, but I'm having a problem with the mousemove event in Safari that works just well in Chrome (and FF).

With the following code :

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
})
```

## Chrome returns something like that:

[image]

## But Safari only gives me that:

[image]

Do you have any idea why?

Thank you!